# como realizar un registro de huellas en php usando un lector biometrico?

Tags: php

se puede realizar un registro de huellas y validación de estas misma en php?
actualmente tengo un dispositivo que sirve para leer la huellas dactilares el dispositivo es un digital persona 4500, como podria hacer este procesos de leer la huellas y validar estas para su ingreso, muy parecido a las marcaciones de trabajo, me podrian decir donde encontrar esta informacion porfavor ya que he buscado y no encontrado,solo encontrado que venden proyectos ya hechos,gracias

Comment: de salida php no puede leer huellas para su validación, tendrías que hacer uso de algo llamado interfaces de coneccion con el equipo, para esto tienes que saber si el equipo puede enviar datos automaticamente por web[Protocolos,socket], si puede escribir en un disco del servidor un archivo de texto... teniendo en consideracion esto entonces puedes 1 consumir web services de php, enviado los datos de lectura y compararlo con los datos guardados previamente o generar un archivo txt, que luego leeras con un cron y compararas igualmente.

Comment: El dispositivo de huellas dactilares debería de venir con su driver, y con APIs para poder gestionar las lecturas. Dudo que entre dichas API haga algo de PHP, ya que normalmente suelen ir en C, pascal, .net, o similar. Una vez tengas procesada la huella con este tipo de apis podrías dejar un fichero de texto en algún sitio que el PHP pudiera abrir y realizar las comprobaciones que quisieras.